# Access denied error on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions

Since a month or so my PC is behaving bit strangely. I am unable to open many of my PdF and word files. I get error like access denied.

Also certain folder when I open in vscode, and when i try to save file after editing, it says you do not have permission.

I am logged in as admin and this folder is within the documents folder.

Any clues???

Comment: Things to try: Do `chkdsk` and verify the SMART data of the disk.

Comment: can you please explain how to do this?

Comment: For disk SMART data use a product such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy). If you have doubts, post a screenshot.